# Filtering through a Google Doc JSON object with Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs, filter, google-docs

How can I simply the code I get back from google docs api request? So I can use it in an angular app and filter through the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question about 8 months ago. I think it would be possible to strip down layers of junk data surrounding the meat of the json object. However, if you're using a google doc as a database, find another alternative if you can.